# Reserved name in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL insert statement is resulting in nothing being added to my table. I have similar statements to other tables that are working fine, so my connection and database setup seems to be working OK. It's something specific to the INSERT that is going wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery_new` (
  `GalleryID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  `Status` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `Title` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `Desc` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `Author` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `MCName` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `Role` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `ImageURL` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `ThumbURL` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `Timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Date` TEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `PHPDate` MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci
)ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT='';
ALTER TABLE `gallery_new` ADD PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`GalleryID`);

ALTER TABLE `gallery_new` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `GalleryID_new` USING BTREE (`GalleryID`);

ALTER TABLE `gallery_new` MODIFY COLUMN `GalleryID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Statements:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(xxxxx, "rpnews", xxxxx, "rpnews");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// GATHER INFO FOR THE DB INSERT
 $date = date("F j, Y"); 
 $phpdate = time();
 $author = ucfirst($user->data['username_clean']);
 $mcname = $user->profile_fields['pf_minecraftname'];
 $title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['posttitle']); 
  $body = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['postbody']); 
if ($user->data['group_id'] == 4) { $role = 'Mod';}
elseif ($user->data['group_id'] == 5) { $role = 'Admin';}
else { $role = 'None';}

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO gallery (Status, Title, Desc, Author, MCName, Role, ImageURL, ThumbURL, Date, PHPDate)
VALUES ('Live', '$title', '$body', '$author', '$mcname', '$role', '$path', '$paththumb', '$date', '$phpdate')");
```

Comment: `mysqli_error` shows something?

Comment: How can I look at that?

Comment: Insert this line after `query()`: `var_dump($mysqli->error);`

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: hmmmmm... string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Desc, Author, MCName, Role, ImageURL, ThumbURL, Date, PHPDate) VALUES ('Live', '' at line 1"

Comment: why are people giving me negative marks... :(

Comment: because you don't use any basic debugging, such as actully checking for errors

Comment: I didn't know how to access it - I assumed errors would siaply the same way PHP warnings do where they just appear on the page... now I know. You've taught me how to fish ;)  Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also `Desc` is a reserved word,use backticks

[Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Answer (score 5):

Wrong table name? `gallery` != `gallery_new`

Comment: gallery_new is there because I used duplicate-tablwe to get the code to show you the structure of the gallery table :)